# How to best organise the deployed/live infrastructure?

Tags: terraform

Our team uses the file system to separate environments (i.e. not workspaces) and we have the following file layout of our terraform code:

Current (i.e. multi-module layout deployment)

```
live
 - dev
    - data_stores
    - open_search
       - main.tf
       - provider.tf
       - terraform.tf
       ...
    - services
        - sqs
          - main.tf
          - provider.tf
 - test
 ...

modules
- s3
- open_search
- sqs
```

One of our team members suggests we switch to a "single-module" deployment layout which looks like that:

```
live
 - dev
    - main.tf
    - provider.tf
    - terraform.tf
 - test

modules
- s3
- open_search
- sqs
```

Note:

- main.tf references/deploys the modules in the "modules" folder
- provider.tf sets up our providers, in our case just the `aws` provide
- terraform.tf sets up the terraform remote backend and other configurations

I am trying to figure out if switching to a single-module deployment layout makes sense. I personally do not see any issues with either of the approaches. One positive point that I can think of is that the single-module dep. is simpler and we can update the infrastructure within a single folder - we do not have to jump to different folders to update different infrastructure pieces.

Anyway, I am curious to hear your thoughts on the above. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the following folder structure, as shown in the screenshot.

[TF Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNmDR.png)

I have all the configuration in tfvars for each stage or environment in the stages folder and refer to the path to the init and plan/apply commands as below.

```
terraform init -backend-config={your backend varfile}

terraform plan -var-file={your varfile}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your strategy, that is still useful. However, your answer does not directly answer the question I am asking.